# Android architecture components with MVP

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

New Android Architecture Components released on google IO 17.

So should we use MVP with architecture components and MVVM?

In google sample on Github, they have used the MVVM model.
[Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample)

Comment: The simple answer is "it depends" - MVVM has a higher learning curve than the standard MVC architecture but offers benefits in terms of testability. However, this kind of question is not really on topic on StackOverflow. Please see the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 13):

About the selection of architectural pattern and its implementation, it always depends on many factors such as team members, app's types, and so on.
In Google's blog post, they have already said that Architecture Components are mainly

> Opinions not Prescriptions.

However, three main components (`Room, ViewModel, ViewData`) are developed with wide-range usage but not focus on any specific pattern.
For example,

- If you are using SQLite to persist local data in your app, you can
  you Room no matter what kind of pattern you are using, it is really a
  great library with a lot of benefits such as reducing boiler plate
  codes, validating SQLite syntax in compilation time, etc.
- Besides, LifeCycle, LiveData, and ViewModel have their own strong
  points. Especially, they address lifecycle-handling issues really well.
- LiveData gives you one more tool of observer pattern which handles data stream reactively. (Like a great feature RxJava provides us).
- ...

At the end, for your question.

> So should we use MVP with architecture components?

The answer is **"it's nice part of Android framework, so why not".**

**Updated:**
If you want to see how a MVP pattern project works with new Architecture Components, please checkout my [repository on Github](https://github.com/quangctkm9207/mvp-android-arch-component). In which I enhance previous MVP model by using Room for local persistence and LifeCycle to create lifecycle-aware Presenter.

Comment: Why don't you use the ViewModel architecture component in order to make the presenter survive to activity recreations or configuration changes? Imho it would offer you great advantages: I took a look at this github repo and it helped me a lot --> https://github.com/armcha/MVP-Architecture-Components

Comment: You do not need to use ViewModel to make Presenter aware of Activity lifecycle. Just implements LifecycleObserver, for example: 
https://github.com/quangctkm9207/mvp-android-arch-component/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/quangnguyen/stackoverflowclient/ui/questions/QuestionsPresenter.java

Comment: I wasn't talking about making the presenter lifecycle aware.. I was talking about the viewmodels' peculiarity which is to survive activity recreations.. So you do not need to implement onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState and all of that stuff :)

Comment: I meant the awareness of Activity lifecycle not Presenter lifecycle by using  LifecycleObserver which is also included in new architecture components. So, your presenter can survive in a such case of screen orientation. I have already given an example above.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently building a template project that uses MVP pattern along with Google Architecture components (Room, LiveData), and compare to mix version of [`Realm`](https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android/?) and LiveData:

https://github.com/duyp/mvp-template

I think some of Google Architecture Components are compatible with MVP Pattern, not only for MVVM :D

You can check out [2 following branches](https://github.com/duyp/mvp-template/branches):

- `realm_livedata`: MVP with Realm and LiveData
- `room_livedata`: MVP with Room persistence library and LiveData

It's much more complex than [`Google sample`](https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android/?) project (I used [`Dagger 2`](https://github.com/google/dagger), RxAndroid, Retrofit, Gson, and clean architecture) hope you find a better solution for your work. If any question or suggestion, you can leave comments or issues on [`my github project`](https://github.com/duyp/mvp-template).

I also created a project using MVVM with new Google architecture components with Realm, Dagger 2, Live data: https://github.com/duyp/mvvm-template

Happy coding!